# Использование дефис-минус (-) в PHP

Tags: php, строки, url

Знакомый пишет движок на php. У нас с ним возник большой спор насчет использования дефиса(в url, названиях папок для моделей/контроллеров/вьюверов и т.д.). Так вот, он говорит что php "крашится" при виде этого знака. В итоге url вида some-interesting-url.com не работает. Хотел он использовать в итоге тире. Возник спор, что в url такая дичь не используется. Он сделал какой-то там "костыль", который заменяет дефис на тире. Допустим, это работает. Но в итоге папки и ссылки на его функции всё равно остаются с тире. Пример ссылки на функцию на скрине. Рассудите двух людей, и помогите найти грамотное решение данной проблемы. Заранее благодарен) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в чем разница между дефисом и тире?

Comment: это дефис (-), а это тире (–)

Comment: @rjhdby это разные типографские символы https://www.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/sections/97/

Comment: Вашему знакомому, судя по всему, еще рано называть себя программистом.

Comment: @zh-mskl9, просто дичь какая-то. Почему "php крашится", какое такое тире...Да пусть бредит чем хочет, может когда-нибудь чему-нибудь и научится.

Comment: Вот и я думаю, что полный бред

Comment: Ну лично я бы не использовал в названиях папок и тем более в названиях доменов символы которые не входят в стандартную ascii таблицу с 7 битными кодами. просто что бы не возникло проблем например если сайт будет хостится на системе с кодировкой файловой системы koi8. А в доменах тем более, потому как человек может захотеть набрать имя с клавиатуры, а на ней только стандартные ascii есть. А что касается php, то ему конечно фиолетово, что там за символы в _тексте_ страницы присутствуют

Comment: @Mike имелось ввиду же там не символы в тексте, а имена `action` - методов в php)

Comment: @sanix А какое отношение имеет `action` в форме html к именам методов в php ? тут 2 варианта - или rewrite не используется и тогда эти символы входят в названия папок где лежат .php файлы (тут вопрос только к web серверу что бы он их нашел) либо rewrite используется, в итоге эта часть url попадет внутри переменной в php, а что при этом php с ней будет делать и будет ли он ее напрямую превращать в имя метода - это уже его личное дело. Может он по этому имени найдет в БД какой обаботчик ему вызывать ...

Comment: @Mike в том то и дело - никакое. но у автора вопроса action=имя_метода_php, который его обработает:D

Comment: @sanix Судя по картинке там длинные тире - это двубайтый UTF8 символ который в общем то допустим, но работать с таким сложно, можно легко попытаться набрать минус на клавиатуре и получить недопустимый символ

Comment: @Mike мб., но это тоже что писать имена переменных на русском в JS - издевательство)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, **использовать "-" (дефис)** в названии функции(метода) или свойства класса - **нельзя**!

Функция/метод/свойство объекта/переменная могут начинаться с буквы/подчеркивания `[A-Za-z_\x7f-\xff]` и могут содержать цифры `[0-9]`.

***UPD:*** как верно подметили в комментариях: наименование может содержать и байты от 127 до 255, но использовать такую возможно **КРАЙНЕ НЕ РЕКОМЕНДУЕТСЯ!**

Можно попытаться обойти ограничение(для свойств, не для методов):

```
class test {
    function __construct() {
        $this->{'have-dash'} = '';  
    }
}

$test = new test();
$test->{'have-dash'} = ':D';
```

**IMHO,** это все, как минимум глупо.

> У нас с ним возник большой спор насчет использования дефиса(в url, названиях папок для моделей/контроллеров/вьюверов и т.д.).

В url использовать можно^1, в php - нельзя, как и в названиях папок и т.д. - нежелательно.

***^1:*** при условии, что это необходимо(для ЧПУ, например) и потом преобразуется уже в нужный вид(т.е. не используется в том виде, который был для названий в php).

**UPD:** под ЧПУ подразумевал:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Все еще много споров по поводу SEO и url с дефисом или подчеркиванием....

> Рассудите двух людей, и помогите найти грамотное решение данной проблемы. Заранее благодарен)

**Использовать "_"**, это считает ***правилом хорошего тона***(в js, например, принято использовать camelCase).

**PS.** А вообще - лучше использовать умный роутинг и тогда такие проблемы отпадут. (не стоит прямиком url в название ф-ции роутить)

Comment: Вы не правы на счет допустимых символов в названиях. php допускает любые символы из верхней части таблицы. http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.basics.php  включая любые двух и более байтные символы UTF-8, включая тире (состоящее из байт 0xE2 0x80). А знак тире или минус - (код 0x2D) он из нижней части таблицы и в диапазон разрешенных символов конечно не входит.

Comment: *при условии, что это необходимо(для ЧПУ, например) и потом преобразуется уже в нужный вид(т.е. не используется в том виде, который был для названий в php).* - какое вообще отношение имеет URL к именованиям внутри языка? *Использовать "_", это считает правилом хорошего тона* - вы с PSR знакомы?

Comment: @Etki у автора роутинг прямиком из url в название ф-ций/методов))) знаком. обновил ответ.

Comment: Имя метода может быть с дефисами, только обработан такой метод должен быть в `__call`

Answer (score 0):

На заметку, используйте правили стандарта PSR-x, родного для PHP.

Русский перевод по ссылке ниже:

https://svyatoslav.biz/misc/psr_translation/

Comment: Ссылка должна быть прямой. Поправь, пока как спам не отметил.

Comment: Прямая - это такая, которая ведёт непосредственно на нужный сайт.